# Load angularjs into angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

The [`$sce`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service is good for inserting html but what if you want to load angularjs content into an angularjs page through an ajax request. Is it possible to use `$sce` for such purpose?

The reason I want to do it is because I want to store form fields and form-logic in a DB table.

Comment: Generally, I consider storing stuff like that in a database a very bad practice.  It makes it hard to edit / hard to maintain.  That said, If you want to load things like that at runtime I believe you'll have to manually $compile the AngularJS / HTML Snippets: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile